# Shortcuts in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have lot of, a really really lot of CSS3 files as well as HTML5 ones, that is the reason why I use form of CSS3 in this way:

```
#wrap #head #strLogo {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Instead of just selecting it this way:

```
#strLogo {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

As it is easier later to find that practicular element in HTML5 document.

Now, I have rule, applied to all anchor tags, like:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

But only one, only the anchor tag representing actual logo (textual) should be different.

I know I can write:

```
#wrap #head #strLogo a {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#wrap #head #strLogo a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

As this link should have same rules on normal and hover state, I managed to write it this way:

```
#wrap #head #strLogo a, #wrap #head #strLogo a:hover {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Could it be written even shorter? For example:

```
#wrap #head #strLogo (a, a:hover) {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: "As it is easier later to find that practicular element in HTML5 document." Ew no. That is not a valid reason to use more selectors than necessary.

Comment: Yes it is valid reason, as it is my personal preference. And main point is how, and not why.

Comment: This isn't about personal preference. If everything was about personal preference you wouldn't even be asking how - you would be doing something and insisting that it should work because that's how you want it to.

Comment: I beleive your personal preference is going from question to question on this site, on which you do not know answer, and then commenting that question is not really needed? For someone who looks at this answer like me, will learn that for that he or she can use SASS or Less as stated in answer bellow.

Comment: @codehorse Very nice feature ctrl+f can not be closed once when opened in sublime text, and just uses space where code should be. Also, as that codes are long, it can happen that before validation I accidentally put two ids with same name.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what my use of the site has to do with the topic at hand, unless you're just making *ad hominem* remarks for their own sake. I will say however that I commented so that others reading your question will learn that it's not the right thing to do, and not a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a more sophisticated version of CSS, you should consider

- [Less](http://lesscss.org/) (The Dynamic Stylesheet Language)
- [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) (Syntactically Awesome Style Sheets)

Comment: That basically means, that it can not be accomplished through native CSS3?

Comment: No it can't. But there are are ways to get around that limitation